# How to count the subdirectories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I want to count the directories that are present in a parent directory but when I run this code, it gives me the following result.

Although I can count the directories without writing the `count` argument in a function, but I used it for my project.

**Given result**

```
Total directories are 0
/home/runner/TestP1/.upm
Total directories are 1
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1/sub
Total directories are 2
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1
Total directories are 2
/home/runner/TestP1/folder2
Total directories are 3
```

**Expected result**

```
/home/runner/TestP1/.upm
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1/sub
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1
/home/runner/TestP1/folder2
Total directories are 4
```

**Code**

```
import os

dirs = []
def listdirs(rootdir, count):
    for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
        d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            dirs.append(d)
            listdirs(d, count)
            count += 1;
            print(d)
    print(f"Total directories are {count}")

rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
count = 0
listdirs(rootdir, count)
```

Comment: `dedent` the count print, twice, i.e. you need the count print outside the loop.

Comment: @Cyttorak I printed the count outside the loop but still getting the same result

Comment: I see, you are using recursion, I did not notice. I will add an answer.

Comment: @Cyttorak I updated the code to print outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested function, and use `count` variable from the outer function, in the inner function, instead of passing `count` as an argument to the recursive function:

```
def listdirs(rootdir, count):
    def recurse(rootdir):
        nonlocal count
        for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
            d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
            if os.path.isdir(d):
                recurse(d)
                count += 1;
                print(d)
    recurse(rootdir)
    print(f"Total directories are {count}")
```

Alternatively, you can keep a flag to judge when to display count:

```
def listdirs(rootdir, count, display_count=True):
    for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
        d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            count = listdirs(d, count, False)
            count += 1;
            print(d)
    if display_count: print(f"Total directories are {count}")
    else: return count
```